# print list of dynamic js file using php function

Tags: php

I have this code for printing js files using php function in my index page:

```
<? PHP
    function admin_js($js, $file = '') {
        global $_admin_js;
        if ($file != '') {
            $file = preg_replace('/\\\/', '/', dirname($file));
        }

        $_admin_js[] = array(
            $js,
            $file
        );
    }

    $_admin_js = array();
    global $_admin_js;
    $value = '';

    foreach($_admin_js as $js) {
        $relative_path = RELATIVE_PATH;
        echo '<script src="' . $relative_path . '/' . preg_replace('/\\\/', '/', $js[0]) . '"></script>' . " \n\t";
    }

    global $_admin_js;
    admin_js('admin/templates/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js');
    admin_js('admin/templates/js/bootstrap.min.js');
?>
```

But in action php output is empty. whats my problem ? how do print ?!

DEMO [HERE](http://jscdn.96.lt/php/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code sequence is wrong.

```
<? PHP
 function admin_js($js, $file = '')
 {
     global $_admin_js;
     if ($file != '')
     {
        $file = preg_replace('/\\\/', '/', dirname($file));
     }

     $_admin_js[] = array( $js, $file);
}

/* here should be the code of declaration */

$_admin_js = array();
global $_admin_js;
$value = '';

// Call this first to populate the array of $_admin_js

admin_js('admin/templates/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js');
admin_js('admin/templates/js/bootstrap.min.js');

//Now you get the filled up array...

foreach($_admin_js as $js)
{
     $relative_path = RELATIVE_PATH;
     echo '<script src="' . $relative_path . '/' . preg_replace('/\\\/', '/', $js[0]) . '"></script>' . " \n\t";
}
```

Comment: @Riad: i need to add `admin_js('admin/templates/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js');` after `foreach($_admin_js as $js)` Because: in each page i add `admin_js('...')` file for load in `<head></head>`. i need to load auto dynamic js files to `<head></head>` for each page so i put `foreach($_admin_js as $js)` in top of my page.